# android-How to change alertdialog items gravity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

this is my alertDialog :

```
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewCar.this);
                builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                       Log.v("this",items[item]+ " ");
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                TextView titleView = (TextView)alert.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android"));
                if (titleView != null) {
                    titleView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
```

this is the output :

[image]

as you can see , the title is right to left but I can't make the items right to left too .

How can I make the items to go from right to left ?

thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create you custom view in xml (or from code) and use

```
builder.setView(customView)
```